# React router dom: Click on Link, refresh the current page but doesn't go to destination page

Tags: reactjs

I am on page '/hello'

I have below component in the page '/hello':

```
<Link to="/world" onClick={() => window.location.reload()}>
   ...some lines of code
</Link>
```

Current behaviour: When I click on Link, '/hello' page will refresh, then nothing happens.

Expected behaviour: After clicking, go to '/world' page, then auto-refresh the /world page.

Thank you so much for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to remove `onClick={() => window.location.reload()}` from the `Link`. Then, if you want to reload this world every time the use redirects to this page, inside world component, in the `useEffect` section define the reload. So, your world component would look something like this:

for functional component:

```
const World = () => {
     useEffect(() => {
        window.location.reload() 
     }, [])

return (
   <>
   </>
)}

export default World
```

Comment: Thank you, but adding the componentDidMount will make it keep reloading. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Oh, I see. Well another approach can be using `window.location.href` as `onClick` function and assigning the address to it. This would cause a refresh while navigating into the new page.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the right answer,
Why don't you just use link to redirect to the world page and use refresh in useEffect

```
<Link to="/world">
//code
</Link>
```

And in the world page

```
import React,{ useEffect } from "react";



const World = ()=>{
 useEffect(() => {
    window.location.reload;
}, []);
//...
return(
//...)
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for answering! Would you like to use the class based component? Sorry I am new to react, so I am not familiar with useEffect

Comment: In the `componentDidMount` section define the reload.